# Java problem using commons-httpclient-3.X.jar

Tags: java, api, yahoo, urlencode, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to pass from commons-httpclient-3.0.jar    to    commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
but changing the jar my code doesn't work any more. 
The problem is that the new library encode automatically the passed uri. 
Is there a way to avoid this? 
I must interact with Yahoo API and I mustn't encode the URI otherwise I can't access to the services.
Here there is a scratch of my code, comparing the two printing line I observe the difference between the passed URI and the used one.

```
 GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod();
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(DeliciousApi.generateRequestToken(), false);
        getMethod.setURI(uri);
        System.out.println("Passed URI: " + uri.getURI());
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println("Used URI: " + getMethod.getURI());
            System.err.println("getMethod failed: " + getMethod.getStatusLine());
        }
```

And this is the output:

```
Passed URI: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=ce4630523j788f883f76314ed3965qw9&oauth_timestamp=1277236486&oauth_consumer_key=hd7sHfs5YVFuh3DRTUFgFgF7GcF4RDtsTXStGdRyJJf7WSuShQAShd2JdiwjIibHsU8YFDgshk7hd32xjA6isnNsT7SkbLS8YDHy&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=53h8x475a66v238j7f43456lhhgg8s7457fwkkdd%26&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"&oauth_callback=oob
Used URI:   https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=ce4630523j788f883f76314ed3965qw9&oauth_timestamp=1277236486&oauth_consumer_key=hd7sHfs5YVFuh3DRTUFgFgF7GcF4RDtsTXStGdRyJJf7WSuShQAShd2JdiwjIibHsU8YFDgshk7hd32xjA6isnNsT7SkbLS8YDHy&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=53h8x475a66v238j7f43456lhhgg8s7457fwkkdd%2526&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=%22en-us%22&oauth_callback=oob
```

getMethod failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Forbidden

coppia: oauth_problem signature_invalid

particolarly:

%26&oauth_version  -->  %2526&oauth_version

and

xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"  -->  xoauth_lang_pref=%22en-us%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid encoding by doing this,

```
      URI uri = new URI(DeliciousApi.generateRequestToken(), true);
```

However, you might get exception on your original URL, which is not properly encoded. You need to encode double quotes. Even better, get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip! This solved my trouble! I was stupid because I never tought before! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would using setUri("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token") followed by setQueryString(*insert string here*) work? I seem to remember having more control over the query string doing it this way...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I've already tried this solution before and the result is the same.

In my project I must use the api commons-httpclient-3.1.jar but I can change the code for calling the yahoo services. Is there another api that can I use for interact whit Yahoo?